# How to reuse an object if it existed

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to determine whether or not a given object has been created. I see there are methods for `class_exists` and `method_exists` but what I'm trying to figure out is if `new Foo()` has been called (and hopefully figure out what variable it was assigned to, but that is not as important).

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this. Why do you need to find out in the first place? There may well be a better solution for what you want to achieve

Comment: You need to specify your use-case because what you ask for is not possible with the bare PHP language, it does not offer such.

Comment: isset($variable) function in php used to determine if a variable is set and is not NULL.

Comment: I wanted to reuse the object if it existed. This file is included by several other files so it's not as simple as testing for isset($foo), as one programmer could've called it $bar...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you are trying to initialize object only once. If this is the case why not to use singleton pattern? This will free you from checking of existence of object:

```
    class MyClass {
      private static $instance;

      private function __construct() {}

      public static function getInstance() {
        if (empty(self::$instance)) {
          self::$instance = new __CLASS__();
        }

        return self::$instance;
      }
    }
```

You can use this code like this:

```
$obj = MyClass::getInstance();
```

With similar approach you can define additional helper static methods which will check whether object was instantiated or not. You just need to keep instance statically inside your class.

Comment: I'm not sure about the effects of making this a singleton (i don't know if others are creating multiples of this object) but what do you think about creating a static method that indicates whether or not the constructer has been called?

Comment: @gandalf007 I wrote exactly this at the and of my first answer. Yes, you can do this and this will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: After seeing the reason you are needing this in the comments above, this is definitely not the way to go about it.**

Here ya go. It could be optimized a little, but should work fine.

Also, passing `get_defined_vars()` to the function every time is necessary because that function only retrieves the vars within the scope it's called. Calling it inside the function would only give the vars within the scope of that function.

```
<?php
function isClassDeclared($class_name, $vars, $return_var_name = FALSE) {
    foreach ($vars AS $name => $val) {
        if (is_object($val) && $val instanceof $class_name)
            return $return_var_name ? $name : TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}

class Foo {}
$foo = new Foo;

echo '<pre>';
var_dump(isClassDeclared('foo', get_defined_vars(), TRUE));
var_dump(isClassDeclared('bar', get_defined_vars(), TRUE));
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: It looks like this would work, I'm nervous aboutlooping through get_defined_vars every time but based on my admittedly vague requirements this solution should work

Comment: Yes, you would be better off using the singleton pattern for what you need.